# DI Compile fails with "Area code not set" error

Tags: best-practice, dependency-injection, exception, magento2.2.4, area

I'm trying to use the `\Magento\Sales\Model\InvoiceOrder` class to invoice some orders. If I include the class in my constructor, however, then I get the "Area code not set: Area code must be set before starting a session." error.

I ran a `bin/magento setup:di:compile -vvv` and found that the exception is being thrown while initialising the "Magento\Payment\Helper\Data" class which requires `Magento\Ui\Config\Reader\Definition\Data` and goes on to run `Magento\Framework\Url->getUrl()` which in turn attempts to create a session.

Is there any way to make this work? I can think of three ways to possibly make it work, but I'm not sure if any of them would be considered best-practice:

1. Use the ObjectManager to get the instance of "InvoiceOrder" rather than Dependency Injection.
2. Set the Area somewhere, like a class constructor, so it can bypass the issue
3. Extend one of the base classes (like "\Magento\Framework\Url") with a plugin which either sets the area or catches the exception.

I'm getting around the issue right now using the Object Manager, but it obviously goes against best practices. Would option 3 be considered good practice, or at-least better practice than the other two options? It seems a bit crazy to set the area in a console command even though it won't really be used.

Comment: Can you add your code snippet?

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? Looking at exactly the same problem right now and the answer below did not apply as I was already using the mentioned Interface.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

In vendor/magento/module-sales/etc/di.xml, you find this line:

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Api\InvoiceOrderInterface" type="Magento\Sales\Model\InvoiceOrder"/>
```

So, in your constructor, instead of requiring `Magento\Sales\Model\InvoiceOrder`, better require `Magento\Sales\Api\InvoiceOrderInterface`.

This will also make your code more robust when upgrading Magento 2, as you now rely on service contracts (as is considered best practise).